# Pinging server returns offline occasionally java Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

So, im trying to iterate through ipaddresses in an arraylist so i can ping them and get data, however, i get the occasional offline server error even when the server is online when i ping it separately. Im using a multithreaded environment. It also can’t be that the server is taking too long to reply because i’ve increased the timeout length and pinging the ip separately has no issues. Any help is appreciated

```
public class PingServer implements Runnable {
    private String serverip;
    public PingServer(String ip) {
        this.serverip = ip;
    }
    public void run() {

        try {
            MinecraftPingReply data = new MinecraftPing().getPing(new MinecraftPingOptions().setHostname(serverip).setPort(25565));
            //sending
            String servercount = data.getPlayers().getOnline() + "/" + data.getPlayers().getMax();


          System.out.println(serverip + " " + servercount + " pineapple");



        } catch (IOException |  IllegalStateException | IllegalArgumentException | JsonSyntaxException exception){
            System.out.println("offline" + serverip + “ ” + exception);
        }


    }
}



java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645)
    at com.corporate.utils.mcping.MinecraftPing.getPing(MinecraftPing.java:66)
    at com.corporate.database.refresh.ReplaceDataDB.run(ReplaceDataDB.java:36)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Exception in thread "Thread-16145" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: There is nothing you can do here. This is an issue outside your code (Assuming the address is correct). The best thing to do is set a timeout and catch the error, maybe try one more time, then skip that server.

Comment: Note: Is it always the same servers? If you are pinging too often then you may be getting blacklisted (temporarily/permanently). Try spacing out your connections, or using fewer threads and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When the server is offline, and you know it's not your failt (i.e. code error/wrong IP...), you can ignore it.

I suggest you to do something like this, to manage who which error are handled :

```java
try {
    // here you code
    online = true;
} catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // here it's your code that create error
} catch (ConnectException | SocketTimeoutException e) {
    // server offline
    online = false;
} catch (Exception e) { // all others issues
    getLogger().severe("Server " + key + " create an error:");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In my case, such as I don't use the same API as you, it was generating "*ConnectException*". Your API seems to depend about "*SocketTimeoutException*". So, I add another handler area.